# New Outlook MailItem saving in Inbox rather than Drafts

Tags: perl, outlook, ole

I have to create emails and save them in an Outlook (2007) Drafts folder.  I am using Perl (ActivePerl 5.12.3) and the Win32::OLE module.  If Outlook is already open it works correctly.  Elsif I instantiate Outlook, the first email saves in the Inbox and the rest in the Drafts folder.  The following demonstrates the problem.

```
use strict;
use Win32::OLE;
use Win32::OLE::Const 'Microsoft Outlook';

my $oMailer;
# Connect to a running version of Outlook
eval { $oMailer =
   Win32::OLE->GetActiveObject('Outlook.Application')
};
die "Outlook not installed" if $@;

# Start up Outlook if not running
unless(defined $oMailer) {
  $oMailer = new Win32::OLE('Outlook.Application', sub {$_[0]->Quit;})
  or die "Unable to start an Outlook instance: $!\n";
}

for (my $i=1; $i <5; $i++) {
  my $oEmail = $oMailer->CreateItem(0) or
    die "Unable to create mail item: $!\n";

  $oEmail->{'To'} = 'me@domain.info';
  $oEmail->{'Subject'} = "This is test #$i";
  $oEmail->{BodyFormat} = olFormatHTML;
  $oEmail->{HTMLBody}   = '<html></html>';

  $oEmail->save();
}
```

The M$ [dox on MailItem.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb175280%28v=office.12%29.aspx) say:

> Saves the Microsoft Outlook item to the current folder or, if this is a new item, to the Outlook default folder for the item type.

I have been unable to find any other reports of this in my googling efforts.  Any idea of how to get it to work as documented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an indication that you never logged to a MAPI session.

Immediately after creating an instance of the Outlook.Application object, retrieve the Namespace object (Application.GetNamespace("MAPI"), then call Namespace.Logon

Comment: That worked!  The Perl version of the code (for future seekers) is: my $namespace = oMailer->GetNamespace('MAPI'); $namespace->Logon();